# How to check a candidate that has a field in the object array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to change the avatar of a user in the comments of the posts, since such a function will be needed once, I want to check whether the avatar has already been changed using the candidate, but in my case it is always True, I do not know how to fix it. The name of the avatar is always the same as the username(after renaming).

```
changeAvatar(req, res, next) {
        const { userName } = req.body

        const condidate = Post.find({
            'comments':{ $elemMatch:{avatar: userName}
         }})
        if(condidate) {return res.json([{ message:'Avatar edited', status: 'success' }])}

        Post.updateMany(
            { 'comments.owner': userName },
            { $set: { 'comments.$.avatar': userName } },
            { arrayFilters: [{'comments.$.owner': userName}]}, 
            ( err, docs ) => {
            }
            ).clone()
            return next()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to change the above lines for $set and arrayFilters in your updateMany statement as follow:

```
        { $set: { 'comments.$[x].avatar': userName } },
        { arrayFilters: [{'x.owner': userName}]},
```

so mongo to be able to update the avatar value for your owner object with the  userName ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, please tell me, this will update all the `comments`, yes?

Comment: It is expected to update only avatar value for the object in the array where owner:userName

Comment: Just for one object? In my case, each comment is an object

Comment: if all of your objects in the array have the key/value pair owner:userName then all of them will be updated ...